# Using lapply with multiple lists of DFs as input to a function

Tags: r, function, for-loop, lapply, mapply

I have 3 subjects who underwent an intervention - so I have pre- and post-treatment DFs for all of them. The 6 final datasets are as follows: `df_pre_sub101, df_post_sub101, df_pre_sub202, df_post_sub202, df_pre_sub303, df_post_sub303`

Below is the code I currently have where I've manually gone in and typed out the dataset names. I'd like to automate this process for when I have more subjects so I don't have to manually go in and type all of these steps for new datasets. Here is the code:

```
# create my necessary pre and post dataframes for each subject
df_pre_sub101 <- read_csv("sub101_pre.csv")
df_post_sub101<- read_csv("sub101_post.csv")
df_pre_sub202<- read_csv("sub202_pre.csv")
df_post_sub202<- read_csv("sub202_post.csv")
df_pre_sub303 <- read_csv("sub303_pre.csv")
df_post_sub303 <- read_csv("sub303_post.csv")

# pull out columns "State" and "MEP amp pre" into df_pre
# pull out columns "State" and "MEP amp post" into df_post
df_pre_sub101 <- df_pre_sub101[ , c("State", "MEP AMP (mV)")] %>%
  rename("mepAMP_pre" = "MEP AMP (mV)")
df_post_sub101 <- df_post_sub101[ , c("State", "MEP AMP (mV)")] %>%
  rename("mepAMP_post" = "MEP AMP (mV)")

df_pre_sub202 <- df_pre_sub202[ , c("State", "MEP AMP (mV)")] %>%
  rename("mepAMP_pre" = "MEP AMP (mV)")
df_post_sub202 <- df_post_sub202[ , c("State", "MEP AMP (mV)")] %>%
  rename("mepAMP_post" = "MEP AMP (mV)")

df_pre_sub303 <- df_pre_sub303[ , c("State", "MEP AMP (mV)")] %>%
  rename("mepAMP_pre" = "MEP AMP (mV)")
df_post_sub303 <- df_post_sub303[ , c("State", "MEP AMP (mV)")] %>%
  rename("mepAMP_pre" = "MEP AMP (mV)")

# combine pre and post DFs per subject, and add in a subID column
df_sub101 <- cbind(df_pre_sub101, mepAMP_post = df_post_sub101$mepAMP_post)
df_sub101 <- cbind(subID = 101, df_sub101)

df_sub202 <- cbind(df_pre_sub202, mepAMP_post = df_post_sub202$mepAMP_post)
df_sub202 <- cbind(subID = 202, df_sub202)

df_sub303 <- cbind(df_pre_sub303, mepAMP_post = df_post_sub303$mepAMP_post)
df_sub303 <- cbind(subID = 303, df_sub303)

# combine rows for different subjects
df_all <- bind_rows(df_sub101, df_sub202, df_sub303)
```

I was told that instead of a for loop, I can try using `lapply`. This is what I have so far:

```
# create my necessary pre and post dataframes for each subject
df_pre_sub101 <- read_csv("sub101_pre.csv")
df_post_sub101<- read_csv("sub101_post.csv")
df_pre_sub202<- read_csv("sub202_pre.csv")
df_post_sub202<- read_csv("sub202_post.csv")
df_pre_sub303 <- read_csv("sub303_pre.csv")
df_post_sub303 <- read_csv("sub303_post.csv")

# create a list of DFs to feed into lapply
df.list.pre <- list(dfRCpre_sub19746, dfRCpre_sub19674, dfRCpre_sub19673)
df.list.post <- list(dfRCpost_sub19746, dfRCpost_sub19674, dfRCpost_sub19673)

# create my function to try and replicate my above code
myfunction <- function(x,y) {
  df.pre <- x[ , c("State", "MEP AMP (mV)")] %>% rename("mepAMP_pre" = "MEP AMP (mV)")
  df.post <- y[ , c("State", "MEP AMP (mV)")] %>% rename("mepAMP_post" = "MEP AMP (mV)")
  df <- cbind(df.pre, mepAMP_post = df.post$mepAMP_post)
}

# use lapply to feed in my pre and post DF lists
result <- lapply(x = df.list.pre, FUN = myfunction, y = df.list.post)
```

However, this gives me an error that "X" is missing. I originally got the above code partially working when I did pre and post DFs separately (so not trying to feed in two lists). I found online that I can use `mapply`, however, the structure this outputs for me is weird. I'd like to get the following dataframe as an output for the above:

[image]

However, I haven't been able to

1. Pass my function over multiple lists (pre and post DFs) using `lapply`
2. Incorporate `df_sub101 <- cbind(subID = 101, dfRC_sub101)` from my original code. This adds in a column `subID` that pastes that subject's ID for all 11 states.
3. I'm not sure if I still need to include `df_all <- bind_rows(df_sub101, df_sub202, df_sub303)` or if `lapply` would automatically append the subjects it iterates through.

Would appreciate some help.

Reproducible dataset example (all follow the same structure):

df_pre_sub101

```
structure(list(State = c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11), 
    `Pulse Time (ms)` = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
    NA, NA), `MEP AMP (mV)` = c(0.197647215643277, 0.0954348832989732, 
    0.523944806307554, 0.625025630825096, 0.924895880371332, 
    0.898288637399673, 0.918388723582029, 1.43350288197398, 2.1276653945446, 
    1.6496229916811, 1.64261059297456), `MEP Max (mV)` = c(0.112193062901497, 
    0.0476949736475945, 0.337814380414784, 0.382357756296794, 
    0.551612275838852, 0.599131107330322, 0.5466592207551, 0.875852793455124, 
    1.34147183597088, 0.968559554219246, 0.960105763541328), 
    `MEP Min (mV)` = c(-0.0854541527417799, -0.0477399096513788, 
    -0.18613042589277, -0.242667874528302, -0.37328360453248, 
    -0.299157530069351, -0.371729502826929, -0.557650088518858, 
    -0.786193558573723, -0.681063437461853, -0.682504829433229
    ), `MEP Max T. (ms)` = c(158.066666666667, 158.866666666667, 
    159.7, 160.244444444444, 160, 160.64, 159.9, 160.74, 159.82, 
    161.28, 160.355555555556), `MEP Min T. (ms)` = c(165.066666666667, 
    166.866666666667, 164.4, 163.577777777778, 163.84, 164.5, 
    165.4, 165.18, 165.58, 166.74, 165.822222222222), `MEP Latency (ms)` = c(28.0666666666667, 
    28.8666666666667, 29.7, 30.2444444444444, 30, 30.64, 29.9, 
    30.74, 29.82, 31.28, 30.3555555555555), `# Trials` = c(3, 
    3, 4, 9, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 9), `# Rejected` = c(7, 
    7, 6, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1), `Rejected Trials` = c("8 22 34 57 73 76 96", 
    "3 14 20 42 45 67 77", "2 6 25 26 41 92", "38", NA, NA, NA, 
    NA, NA, NA, "1")), row.names = c(NA, -11L), spec = structure(list(
    cols = list(State = structure(list(), class = c("collector_double", 
    "collector")), `Pulse Time (ms)` = structure(list(), class = c("collector_logical", 
    "collector")), `MEP AMP (mV)` = structure(list(), class = c("collector_double", 
    "collector")), `MEP Max (mV)` = structure(list(), class = c("collector_double", 
    "collector")), `MEP Min (mV)` = structure(list(), class = c("collector_double", 
    "collector")), `MEP Max T. (ms)` = structure(list(), class = c("collector_double", 
    "collector")), `MEP Min T. (ms)` = structure(list(), class = c("collector_double", 
    "collector")), `MEP Latency (ms)` = structure(list(), class = c("collector_double", 
    "collector")), `# Trials` = structure(list(), class = c("collector_double", 
    "collector")), `# Rejected` = structure(list(), class = c("collector_double", 
    "collector")), `Rejected Trials` = structure(list(), class = c("collector_character", 
    "collector"))), default = structure(list(), class = c("collector_guess", 
    "collector")), delim = ","), class = "col_spec"), problems = <pointer: 0x10d9c71f0>, class = c("spec_tbl_df", 
"tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually there is no need for `lapply` as `readr::read_csv` can import multiple files at once. To this end create a list or vector containing your file names which e.g. could be achieved via `list.files`. Then you could read your files at once and bind them by row where using the `id` argument you can add an identifier for each file aka the filename. Afterwards you can clean up the file identifier to get the subject id and the type of treatment. Finally, select your desired columns and reshape to wide.

The code below first creates four example files based on the example data you provided.

```r
# Make example files. Save in a temporary dictionary
fns <- paste0("sub", rep(c(101, 202), each = 2), "_", rep(c("pre", "post"), 2), ".csv")
path <- tempdir()
lapply(fns, \(x) write.csv(dat, file.path(path, x), row.names = FALSE))

library(readr)
library(dplyr, warn=FALSE)
library(tidyr)

# Get a list of the files to red
files <- list.files(path, pattern = "\\.csv", full.names = TRUE)

# Read files and add an id
read_csv(files, id = "file") |>
  # Clean file name
  mutate(file = gsub("\\.csv", "", basename(file))) |>
  # separate into subject and treatment columns
  separate(file, into = c("subject", "treatment"), sep = "_") |> 
  # Select and rename
  select(subject, treatment, State, mepAMP = "MEP AMP (mV)") |> 
  pivot_wider(names_from = treatment, values_from = mepAMP, names_prefix = "mepAMP_")

#> # A tibble: 22 × 4
#>    subject State mepAMP_post mepAMP_pre
#>    <chr>   <dbl>       <dbl>      <dbl>
#>  1 sub101      1      0.198      0.198 
#>  2 sub101      2      0.0954     0.0954
#>  3 sub101      3      0.524      0.524 
#>  4 sub101      4      0.625      0.625 
#>  5 sub101      5      0.925      0.925 
#>  6 sub101      6      0.898      0.898 
#>  7 sub101      7      0.918      0.918 
#>  8 sub101      8      1.43       1.43  
#>  9 sub101      9      2.13       2.13  
#> 10 sub101     10      1.65       1.65  
#> # ℹ 12 more rows
```

**DATA**

```
dat <- structure(list(
  State = c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11),
  `Pulse Time (ms)` = c(
    NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA,
    NA, NA
  ), `MEP AMP (mV)` = c(
    0.197647215643277, 0.0954348832989732,
    0.523944806307554, 0.625025630825096, 0.924895880371332,
    0.898288637399673, 0.918388723582029, 1.43350288197398, 2.1276653945446,
    1.6496229916811, 1.64261059297456
  ), `MEP Max (mV)` = c(
    0.112193062901497,
    0.0476949736475945, 0.337814380414784, 0.382357756296794,
    0.551612275838852, 0.599131107330322, 0.5466592207551, 0.875852793455124,
    1.34147183597088, 0.968559554219246, 0.960105763541328
  ),
  `MEP Min (mV)` = c(
    -0.0854541527417799, -0.0477399096513788,
    -0.18613042589277, -0.242667874528302, -0.37328360453248,
    -0.299157530069351, -0.371729502826929, -0.557650088518858,
    -0.786193558573723, -0.681063437461853, -0.682504829433229
  ), `MEP Max T. (ms)` = c(
    158.066666666667, 158.866666666667,
    159.7, 160.244444444444, 160, 160.64, 159.9, 160.74, 159.82,
    161.28, 160.355555555556
  ), `MEP Min T. (ms)` = c(
    165.066666666667,
    166.866666666667, 164.4, 163.577777777778, 163.84, 164.5,
    165.4, 165.18, 165.58, 166.74, 165.822222222222
  ), `MEP Latency (ms)` = c(
    28.0666666666667,
    28.8666666666667, 29.7, 30.2444444444444, 30, 30.64, 29.9,
    30.74, 29.82, 31.28, 30.3555555555555
  ), `# Trials` = c(
    3,
    3, 4, 9, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 9
  ), `# Rejected` = c(
    7,
    7, 6, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1
  ), `Rejected Trials` = c(
    "8 22 34 57 73 76 96",
    "3 14 20 42 45 67 77", "2 6 25 26 41 92", "38", NA, NA, NA,
    NA, NA, NA, "1"
  )
), row.names = c(NA, -11L), spec = structure(list(
  cols = list(State = structure(list(), class = c(
    "collector_double",
    "collector"
  )), `Pulse Time (ms)` = structure(list(), class = c(
    "collector_logical",
    "collector"
  )), `MEP AMP (mV)` = structure(list(), class = c(
    "collector_double",
    "collector"
  )), `MEP Max (mV)` = structure(list(), class = c(
    "collector_double",
    "collector"
  )), `MEP Min (mV)` = structure(list(), class = c(
    "collector_double",
    "collector"
  )), `MEP Max T. (ms)` = structure(list(), class = c(
    "collector_double",
    "collector"
  )), `MEP Min T. (ms)` = structure(list(), class = c(
    "collector_double",
    "collector"
  )), `MEP Latency (ms)` = structure(list(), class = c(
    "collector_double",
    "collector"
  )), `# Trials` = structure(list(), class = c(
    "collector_double",
    "collector"
  )), `# Rejected` = structure(list(), class = c(
    "collector_double",
    "collector"
  )), `Rejected Trials` = structure(list(), class = c(
    "collector_character",
    "collector"
  ))), default = structure(list(), class = c(
    "collector_guess",
    "collector"
  )), delim = ","
), class = "col_spec"), class = c(
  "spec_tbl_df",
  "tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"
))
```

Comment: Thank you for your comment. Unfortunately this doesn't give me exactly what I want - you have just the one `dat` that it cycles through. However, for each `sub_pre` and `sub_post` there is a separate `df`. Is there a way to have the `lapply` cycle through each one? Right now in the final output it just inputs the same values from `dat` repeated for the different subjects I specify (101, 202, 303, etc)

Comment: Well, the first three lines are just meant to create example datasets and files so that we get a working example code. Of course do you have to replace `path` with the real name of the directory where your csv files are stored. A second approach would be to create the vector of filenames manually if you prefer some work, i.e. do `files <- c("sub101_pre.csv", ""sub101_post.csv", ...)`. Then run the code again.